# Accessing HBase using java api within WebLogic

Tags: hbase, cloudera, apache-zookeeper, weblogic11g

I have a java native api to access HBase and it works fine as a standalone program. But when I deploy same jar file as part of JAX-RS service, it's not able to get zookeeper.

I have given below both logs when accessed (doesn't work) from weblogic and accessed (works fine) as a standalone java program using same jar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the log when accessed within WebLogic 10.3.5 and it doesn't work.

```
2013-07-19 14:15:30 INFO  class:68 - *************************************************
2013-07-19 14:15:30 INFO  class:69 - HBase configuration info :: zookeeperQuorum -->192.168.56.101, zookeeperClientPort -->2181, hbaseMaster -->192.168.56.101:60000
2013-07-19 14:15:30 INFO  class:72 - *************************************************
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory:42 - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, about=, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory:42 - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, about=, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], type=DEFAULT, always=false, sampleName=Ops)
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG MetricsSystemImpl:220 - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG Groups:180 -  Creating new Groups object
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:46 - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:55 - Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:56 - java.library.path=C:\Java\JROCKI~1.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_ocp360\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Java\JROCKI~1.0\jre\bin;C:\Java\JROCKI~1.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-4.1.0;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Oracl;C:\Users\user123\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts;C:\Softwares\npp.6.3.2.bin\unicode\notepad++.exe;C:\Python\Python27;C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Softwares\depot_tools;C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~3\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8;.
2013-07-19 14:15:30 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback:40 - Falling back to shell based
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback:44 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG Groups:66 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:175 - hadoop login
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:124 - hadoop login commit
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:154 - using local user:NTUserPrincipal: user123
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:697 - UGI loginUser:user123 (auth:SIMPLE)
2013-07-19 14:15:30 DEBUG ZKUtil:120 - hconnection opening connection to ZooKeeper with ensemble (192.168.56.101:2181)
2013-07-19 14:15:30 INFO  RecoverableZooKeeper:104 - The identifier of this process is 55380@WIN75CB245190F
2013-07-19 14:15:30 WARN  RecoverableZooKeeper:219 - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2013-07-19 14:15:30 INFO  RetryCounter:53 - Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...
2013-07-19 14:15:32 WARN  RecoverableZooKeeper:219 - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2013-07-19 14:15:32 INFO  RetryCounter:53 - Sleeping 4000ms before retry #2...
2013-07-19 14:15:37 WARN  RecoverableZooKeeper:219 - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2013-07-19 14:15:37 INFO  RetryCounter:53 - Sleeping 8000ms before retry #3...
2013-07-19 14:15:45 WARN  RecoverableZooKeeper:219 - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
2013-07-19 14:15:45 ERROR RecoverableZooKeeper:221 - ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
2013-07-19 14:15:45 WARN  ZKUtil:453 - hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ClusterId.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.getId(ClusterId.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.hasId(ClusterId.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableFactory.createHTableInterface(HTableFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.createHTable(HTablePool.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.findOrCreateTable(HTablePool.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.getTable(HTablePool.java:174)
    at com.cap1.hbase.lookup.HBaseProcessImpl.processTrnx(HBaseProcessImpl.java:87)
    at com.cap1.hbase.lookup.HBaseProcessImpl.processRecord(HBaseProcessImpl.java:64)
    at com.cap1.hbase.callable.HBaseCallable.processTrxns(HBaseCallable.java:47)
    at com.cap1.hbase.callable.HBaseCallable.call(HBaseCallable.java:38)
    at com.cap1.hbase.callable.HBaseCallable.call(HBaseCallable.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Below is the log when same jar file accessed as a standalone java program.

```
2013-07-19 14:22:28 INFO  class:68 - *************************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:28 INFO  class:69 - HBase configuration info :: zookeeperQuorum -->192.168.56.101, zookeeperClientPort -->2181, hbaseMaster -->192.168.56.101:60000
2013-07-19 14:22:28 INFO  class:72 - *************************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory:42 - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, about=, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], always=false, type=DEFAULT, sampleName=Ops)
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory:42 - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(valueName=Time, about=, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], always=false, type=DEFAULT, sampleName=Ops)
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG MetricsSystemImpl:220 - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG Groups:180 -  Creating new Groups object
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:46 - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:55 - Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader:56 - java.library.path=C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_29\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-4.1.0;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Oracl;C:\Users\user123\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts;C:\Softwares\npp.6.3.2.bin\unicode\notepad++.exe;C:\Python\Python27;C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Softwares\depot_tools;C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;;.
2013-07-19 14:22:29 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback:40 - Falling back to shell based
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback:44 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG Groups:66 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:175 - hadoop login
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:124 - hadoop login commit
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:154 - using local user:NTUserPrincipal: user123
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:697 - UGI loginUser:user123 (auth:SIMPLE)
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:120 - hconnection opening connection to ZooKeeper with ensemble (192.168.56.101:2181)
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  RecoverableZooKeeper:104 - The identifier of this process is 50384@WIN75CB245190F
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZooKeeperWatcher:273 - hconnection Received ZooKeeper Event, type=None, state=SyncConnected, path=null
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZooKeeperWatcher:350 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a connected
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:1601 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Retrieved 36 byte(s) of data from znode /hbase/hbaseid; data=494de2c7-aa9c-4b24-9f2c-90ba6...
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:423 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Set watcher on existing znode /hbase/master
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:1601 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Retrieved 36 byte(s) of data from znode /hbase/master and set watcher; \x00\x00ubuntu-12.04.2,47663,...
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:423 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Set watcher on existing znode /hbase/root-region-server
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:1601 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Retrieved 34 byte(s) of data from znode /hbase/root-region-server and set watcher; ubuntu-12.04.2,50780,13742537...
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseRPC:102 - Using RpcEngine: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:860 - The ping interval is60000ms.
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ZKUtil:1601 - hconnection-0x13ff7e7fc02000a Retrieved 34 byte(s) of data from znode /hbase/root-region-server and set watcher; ubuntu-12.04.2,50780,13742537...
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:875 - Looked up root region location, connection=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@1077fc9; serverName=ubuntu-12.04.2,50780,1374253744820
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:434 - Connecting to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$ConnectionId@430581cd
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #0
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:575 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123: starting, having connections 1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #0
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: getProtocolVersion 36
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: getClosestRowBefore 5
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:1266 - Cached location for .META.,,1.1028785192 is ubuntu-12.04.2:50780
2013-07-19 14:22:29 WARN  Configuration:824 - hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #2
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #2
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: getClosestRowBefore 3
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG MetaScanner:200 - Scanning .META. starting at row=HBASE_TEST_TABLE,,00000000000000 for max=10 rows using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@1077fc9
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #3
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #3
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: openScanner 3
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #4
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #4
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: next 6
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:1266 - Cached location for HBASE_TEST_TABLE,,1373942516744.9243ede59ac4a179cae677d7c4ca964c. is ubuntu-12.04.2:50780
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #5
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #5
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: close 2
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:145 - ****************************************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:146 - Start row key --> 8f064a8b5da9b68adbaf0db302363dee, Stop row key --> 8f064a8b5da9b68adbaf0db302363def
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:148 - *****************************************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:251 - ***********************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:252 - Filter info:: FilterList OR (5/6): [SingleColumnValueFilter (ca, city, EQUAL, Chicago), SingleColumnValueFilter (ca, state, EQUAL, IL), SingleColumnValueFilter (ca, country, EQUAL, ), SingleColumnValueFilter (ca, mcc, EQUAL, 5814), SingleColumnValueFilter (ca, terminal_owner, EQUAL, )]
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  HBaseProcessImpl:253 - ***********************************************
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ClientScanner:90 - Creating scanner over HBASE_TEST_TABLE starting at key '8f064a8b5da9b68adbaf0db302363dee'
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ClientScanner:198 - Advancing internal scanner to startKey at '8f064a8b5da9b68adbaf0db302363dee'
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #6
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #6
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: openScanner 3
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #7
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #7
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: next 5
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:608 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 sending #8
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG HBaseClient:649 - IPC Client (6888942) connection to ubuntu-12.04.2/192.168.56.101:50780 from user123 got value #8
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG RPCEngine:92 - Call: close 1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 DEBUG ClientScanner:185 - Finished with scanning at {NAME => 'HBASE_TEST_TABLE,,1373942516744.9243ede59ac4a179cae677d7c4ca964c.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => 9243ede59ac4a179cae677d7c4ca964c,}
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  TaskExecutorService:87 -  getActiveCount:0 getCompletedTaskCount:1 getCorePoolSize:10 getLargestPoolSize:10 getPoolSize:10 getTaskCount:1 getQueue().size():0
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  CustomExecutorPool:143 - added executor back to pool
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  DefaultRequestHandler:59 - Successfully processed payLoad:: d7ca6619-cee6-498f-91a8-bb18de7776c8 with size::1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  MerchantInfoLookup:126 - Request Identifier:: d7ca6619-cee6-498f-91a8-bb18de7776c8
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  MerchantInfoLookup:127 - Response list size:: 1
2013-07-19 14:22:29 INFO  MerchantInfoLookup:128 - ****************** OUTPUT RECORD ****************************
```

Comment: I deployed same web service on Tomcat and works fine.  It seems issue is with WebLogic and not with HBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and fixed issue. It was related to SASL.

Here is description:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1696
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.zookeeper.user/2897
https://gist.github.com/barkbay/4153107